# Earliest exampe of mind-control failing due to obvious physiological/psychological differences?

Tags: history-of, science-fiction-genre, mind-control

Mind-controlling aliens are science fiction's staple and have been like that for quite some time.  There even is [a recent Hot Question about one of the most popular and respected sci-fi franchises](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/140055/how-many-times-was-picards-mind-taken-over) that asks just *how many* times was protagonist's mind taken over.

Now, my question is not about the earliest work that features mind-controlling aliens, since that trope can trace its roots back to stories about possesion by devil/demons/faerie/gods, and the answer would probably include line "which was popularised by H.P. Lovecraft, of course", of course.

You see, the trope is so well-established, that it seems creators don't feel obliged to justify its use in the story. And I've never seen someone else wondering how psychic powers of, say, a crustacean linked to a hive mind, or an emotionless grey-skinned ship-dweller with no digestive tract, can be compatible with an average human mind.

But there's bound to be some author who also thought about that.

Therefore, my question is: what's the earliest work of fiction depicting a race of psychic aliens failing to mind-control humans at all, due to theirs and human's mind being too different?

(I can also accept the reverse: psychic humans failing to mind-control aliens.)

Comment: I don't think this is quite what you're looking for (which is why I'm leaving it as a comment), but in Ursula Le Guin's Hainish books telepathic lying is impossible — except for the Shing from *City of Illusions* (1967), who are so alien that this rule doesn't apply to them. (But mind control is still possible in both directions, and a major part of the plot.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[John Carter of Mars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Carter_of_Mars) (1912) features this for [telephaty](http://barsoom.wikia.com/wiki/John_Carter). Martians can't read John Carter's mind while he can read theirs just as easily as they can each other. No explanation is ushered that I know of.

In [Larry Niven's Known Space universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known_Space) (1964-1975) Pak Protectors are immune to Thrintun mind control, due to their multilobed brain structure.

An earlier example, but not exactly what you're asking, appears in [The Jungle Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jungle_Book) (1894) where  Mowgli as a human is the only creature in the jungle who's immune to Kaa's hypnosis.

Comment: That's pretty much a perfect answer. An early-but-not-so-good example, an explicit early example and a pre-sci-fi example that counts in spirit, but not in technicality.